# Socially adept person

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Can you please help me paraphrase the sentence:

> *It made it very hard for me to become socially adept*

so that the meaning of "socially adept" is expressed in a single noun phrase or a noun? As in:

> *It made me a _________.* (some kind of person)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is **well-adjusted**, which Merriam-Webster defines as "able to deal with other people in a normal or healthy way".

However, you can be well-adjusted but not truly *adept*, which suggests a high degree of ability.  Whether **well-adjusted** fits will depend on what you mean by "adept".